# How to replace part of the system log tail with other text?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a system log that looks like:

```
[timestamp]: [eventA] the system has started.
[timestamp]: [eventB] eventB detail is stored at <filepath>
```

The `<filepath>` look like `"/var/usr/eventB_timestamp.txt"`

I don't usually look at the whole log as it is continually generated, so I usually use "`tail -F <logpath>`" to see these events. The main difficulty is that I have to open the `<filepath>` manually to see eventB, for example. This is very inefficient. How do I replace the message line:

```
[timestamp]: [eventB] eventB detail is stored at <filepath>
```

with

```
[timestamp]: [eventB] + content of <filepath>
```

I am thinking of something alone the line of `grep` then `sed/awk`. As I am very new to shell scripting, is there a reliable way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to open the last instance of corresponding records detail file you can do this

```
tail ... | tac | awk '/eventB/{print $NF; exit}' | xargs cat
```

reverse the output, find the first pattern, extract file name and print the contents.

Answer (score 0):

**/tmp/test/file.log:**

```
[timestamp]: [eventA] the system has started.
[timestamp]: [eventB] eventB detail is stored at /tmp/test/evenlog.file
[timestamp]: [eventC] foo foo foo.
```

**/tmp/test/evenlog.file:**

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Run command:

```
sed 's/\(.*[eventB\].*stored.at.\)\(.*\)/printf [*EventB*]:;cat \2 | xargs echo /e' /tmp/test/file.log
```

Output:

```
[timestamp]: [eventA] the system has started.
[*EventB*]:line 1 line 2 line 3
[timestamp]: [eventC] foo foo foo.
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
#!/bin/sh

tail -F logfile | while read line; do
  echo "$line"
  case "$line" in
    *"eventB detail is stored at"*)
      filepath="${line##* }"
      if [ -f "$filepath" ]; then
        sed 's/^/    /' "$filepath"
      else
        echo "ERROR: file missing"
      fi
      ;;
  esac
done
```

This tails your log, reading and printing each line, and then for lines that match a pattern, takes the last word on the line as `$filepath`, and if a file by that name exists, prints it .. indended, for your reading pleasure.

---

You could implement the same functionality in awk, with less typing:

```
tail -F logfile | awk '
   1;
   /eventB detail is stored at/ {
      file=$NF
      while (getline < file) {
         printf("\t%s\n", $0);
      }
      close(file)
   }
'
```

Note that this awk solution fails pretty spectacularly if the file in question does not exist.  So if you go with an awk solution, this could be your starting point, but should not be your final solution.  YMMV.  Not responsible for use or misuse.  May contain nuts.